Two text button in row center aligned compose
I have been trying to make two text buttons in row with a divider all centrally aligned. I want some like this

For this i have used following code so far
 Box(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), // Occupy full width
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center // Center content horizontally
        ) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(IntrinsicSize.Min),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center, // Center items horizontally
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically // Center vertically (optional)
            ) {
                TextButton(onClick = { /* Action for Button 1 */ }) {
                    Text(modifier = Modifier, text = "Button 1")
                }

                Divider(
                    color = Color.Gray,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxHeight()
                        .width(1.dp)
                )

                TextButton(onClick = { /* Action for Button 2 */ }) {
                    Text("Button 2")
                }
            }
        }

But not able to make the buttons centrally aligned.  This is my result

Any one can help me out !

In your Row instead of Arrangement.Center, use Arrangement.SpaceEvenly:

Place children such that they are spaced evenly across the main axis, including free space before the first child and after the last child. Visually: #1#2#3# for LTR and #3#2#1# for RTL.

Row(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(IntrinsicSize.Min),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically 
) {
    ...
}

This will make the buttons clickable only in the area their content is rendered in. In order to make their clikable area as large as possible, use the weight(1f) modifier:
Row(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(IntrinsicSize.Min),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
) {
    TextButton(
        onClick = { /* Action for Button 1 */ },
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
    ) {
        Text(modifier = Modifier, text = "Button 1")
    }

    Divider(
        color = Color.Gray,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .width(1.dp)
    )

    TextButton(
        onClick = { /* Action for Button 2 */ },
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
    ) {
        Text("Button 2")
    }
}


Can i make the button clickable to whole space available. This is will make button centered, and clickable area restrict to only text length

Of course you can - check the edited answer!

Confirm whether the solution has helped you!

@sweak Good answer, Note that there also is a dedicated VerticalDivider Composable available that you can use.
